# Save file to Sharepoint Document Library by NETWORK SERVICE

Tags: sharepoint, windows-server-2008-r2, sharepoint-2010, fax

First of all, I apologise for any inaccuracy/mistakes - it is my first post here.

Here is the scenario:

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 with roles:

- Active Directory
- Fax Server
- Web Server (IIS)
- File Services
- Printing Server
- Application Server
- There is also Desktop Experience Feature for accessing UNC shares from localhost

I have installed SharePoint Foundation 2010 on this server. On Default SP Web App (which is managed by SPIntranetAppPool (identity - SPIntranetSite) ) i have images library called "Faxes".

Fax messages are received by fax process (FXSVC.EXE) which has NETWORK SERVICE identity.

The problem is: I want fax process to save incoming faxes to SP library. I set incoming routing for fax server role to save in "\host\Faxes" but it doesn't. I also give permissions in "Faxes" SP Library for NETWORK SERVICE. But it doesn't work. The problem is harder because it doesn't show any clue in fax role event log.

I really appreciate any clue or help.

Comment: not familiar with the fax server at all but have you tried running it as a normal user? Would suspect that the user would need admin rights but you could use it as a test just to see what would happen.

Comment: It is not possible change user to normal AD user. From unknown reason fax service accepts only build-in  service roles (Network Service , Local Service , System Local) even it has right groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cleaner approach to this might be to mail-enable your library and configure the fax server to mail new faxes to the library's address.  I know that seems a bit much since they're both on the same machine, but it has the advantage of using simple and well-understood technology in both SP and Fax Server.

Comment: You're right. I have set up incoming emails to farm and configured library to get emails. It is working. Thank you very much.